# EF, AddOrUpdate() requires IDbSet instead of DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
using (var SMC = new SuppliesMasterContext())
{
    var claim_items = _coba.SelectMany(r => r.Claim_items).ToArray();
    SMC.AddRange(_coba); //Insert claims
    SMC.Set<Claim_item>().AddOrUpdate(claim_items); //Insert claim items
    SMC.SaveChanges();
}
```

This error happens on the line with `AddOrUpdate()`:

> 'DbSet<Claim_item>' does not contain a definition for 'AddOrUpdate' and the best extension method overload 'DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate<Claim_item>(IDbSet<Claim_item>, params Claim_item[])' requires a receiver of type 'IDbSet<Claim_item>'

Usings are as follows:

```
using Helpers;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Goal: to update `claim_item` if one is already present in dataset

Comment: If you have primary key defined, I think it's enough to insert new entries. EF should resolve existing IDs on its own.

Comment: Have you mixed up EF Core and EF 6.2 methods perhaps? Saving disconnected entities is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities) - if the (missing) entity has autogenerated keys, a simple `Update` will work. That should be configured inside the context though, which should have a `DbSet<Claim_Item>` ClaimItems` property.

Comment: You haven't posted the entity classes or the model configuration so one can only make guesses and point to the docs. Using `Set<Claim_item>()` means that EF Core has no idea how that entity is configured anyway.

Comment: Can you please hint me towards proper usage of AddOrUpdate?